# Can I use Pathauto with additional url values?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Is it possible to use pathauto url aliases and still use additional url parameters?

For example, I use pathauto for polls to map "node/123" to "poll/title-of-my-poll".
The poll results are at "node/123/results" but using "poll/title-of-my-poll/results" doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Sub-pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto) is for exactly that purpose.

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias.
>
> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the Pathauto module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed internal non-administrative URLs.